# Acessing csv in _data folder of Jekyll using an include tag

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to simplify the organization and use of data for a Jekyll website. I am trying to access individual rows or values in the CSV, which is successful using this snippet:

```
{%- include speclocator.html name="Thing" -%}
```

Data is located in folders under the _data folder, as below:

```
_data/FOLDER1/specifications.csv, 
_data/FOLDER2/specifications.csv, 
_data/FOLDER3/specifications.csv,
etc.
```

The include to access the CSV by named column:

```
{%- for spec in site.data.FOLDER1.specifications -%}
{%- if spec.name == include.name -%}
{{ spec.value | strip }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The snippet in the post:

```
{%- for specification in site.data.FOLDER1.specifications -%}
<tr>
<td><strong>{{specification.name}}</strong></td>
<td>{{specification.value}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I use a variable for FOLDER1, so that I can use this for multiple posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse your includes for multiple data sources, you can use bracket notation like this :

```
{%- include speclocator.html name="Thing" data_source="FOLDER1" -%}
```

or, if you have a page variable like `data_source: FOLDER1`

```
{%- include speclocator.html name="Thing" data_source=page.data_source -%}
```

In your include :

```
{%- for spec in site.data[include.data_source]["specifications"] -%}
  {%- if spec.name == include.name -%}
    {{ spec.value | strip }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked. How would I use a variable for FOLDER1 in the first snippet? I am trying to set the value to something that an be changed with either a YML or CSV value. i.e. {%- include speclocator.html name="Thing" data_source="{{page.folder1value}}" -%}